# I would like to automate data extraction from an API and a for-loop using a Bash script but getting an error

Tags: bash, curl

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a gpu_array=("rtx3060", "rtx3070", "rtx3080", "rtx3090", "rx6700")
#host = "http://192.168.1.31:5000/"

for gpu in ${gpu_array[*]}; do
    gpu_url = $"http://192.168.1.31:5000/$gpu"
    value = $(curl "${gpu_url}") 
    echo $value>> trial.txt
done
```

"""
trial.sh: line 8: value: command not found
trial.sh: line 7: gpu_url: command not found
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
trial.sh: line 8: value: command not found
trial.sh: line 7: gpu_url: command not found
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
trial.sh: line 8: value: command not found
"""

Comment: Install curl and also change $"http://192.168.1.31:5000/$gpu" to "http://192.168.1.31:5000/$gpu"

Comment: Remove blanks around the `=`. Also remove the `,`s in the array initialization.

Comment: [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) would've pointed out most of the problems here; use it!

Answer (score 0):

The array elements are separated by spaces, no commas. The double quotes are not needed, as the elements don't contain any special characters, but they don't hurt.

```
declare -a gpu_array=(rtx3060 rtx3070 rtx3080 rtx3090 rx6700)
```

Don't use `$"..."`, it's used for localization. Plain `"..."` is enough here, in fact, you don't need any quotes here:

```
gpu_url=http://192.168.1.31:5000/$gpu
```

Note there are no spaces around the assignment operator. If you use spaces, bash takes the variable name as the command to run and `=` as its first parameter. That's not what you usually want.

```
gpu_url=http://192.168.1.31:5000/$gpu
value=$(curl "$gpu_url")
```

BTW, the standard way of iterating over the array would be

```
for gpu in "${gpu_array[@]}"; do
```

It'd work correctly even if the array elements contained spaces.

For the same reason, it's a good practice to always double quote the variables (unless you want to split the value on whitespace).

```
echo "$value"
```

This can still do something unexpected if the value is `-n` in some shells, so it's safer to use echo only for constant strings and use `printf` for dynamic contents.

```
printf '%s\n' "$value"
```